# how do I solve this seperable equation with so many terms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve given differential equation by separation of variables

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy+3x-y-3}{xy-2x+4y-8}$$

I started by multiplying each side by the denominator to get

$$(xy-2x+4y-8) dy = (xy+3x-y-3) dx$$
Now that there is $xy$ on each side of the equation do they cancel off or no because they are being multiplied by $dy$ or $dx$. How do I proceed? I'm getting a little discourage because this is the third separable differential equation I have come across and they all have taken a long time and involved lots of writing and are error prone. Is that right, in general differential equations are long and tedious (e.g. involve two integratoins and more)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{xy+3x-y-3}{xy-2x+4y-8}=\frac{y(x-1)+3(x-1)}{x(y-2)+4(y-2)}=$$
$$=\frac{(x-1)(y+3)}{(y-2)(x+4)}\iff\frac{y-2}{y+3}dy=\frac{x-1}{x+4}dx$$

Comment: How do you integrate that?

Comment: Left part $y-5\ln(y-3)$ and right part $x-6\ln(x+4)$